# Movie with children playing amongst travelers stranded at a bus station

Tags: story-identification, aliens

A few years ago I saw a scifi movie about a group of travelers stranded at what I believe might have been a bus station (I don't remember that detail with any certainty).  There were 2 children (a boy and a girl) who were running around and everyone thought they belonged to someone else there.  As it turned out, the children were aliens that reverted to their true form and began hunting down the travelers.  I've been searching all over the internet but can't come up with the name of the movie.  Does anyone know the name of it?

Comment: What language/nationality was the film? Was it a fairly new film, or an old one? Any other things you remember; how it ends, what the kids/aliens look like, how they hunt etc.?

Comment: Appreciate the willingness to help.  Another person recognized it as Terminal Invasion.  Plot summary and scenes from the film on YouTube confirmed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like it might be [Terminal Invasion](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0322008/). It stars Bruce Campbell and takes place in a small airport terminal. [Here's a plot summary.](http://www.sideorderofninjas.com/reviews/terminal.html)

There are a few [scenes from the film on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RAV518kMVzY) - does this look like what you remember?

Comment: That's the one!  Thanks!

Comment: Btw, Terminal Invasion _did_ come up in my web searches, but the results never gave enough info for me to think that was the movie I was looking for.  Your info was more extensive and really helped.