# Film where aliens looking like humans are waiting in an airport closed due to snowstorm

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I saw the movie 6 - 7 years back on cable tv, from the looks of it it seemed to be made in the late 1990's or early 2000's. Unfortunately I could not see the complete movie. The story goes like--

1. Some people are waiting at a small airport because snowstorm activity has cancelled all flights in and out. There are two children in the group as well (one boy and a girl).
2. Somehow they discover there are aliens looking like humans among them.
3. They decide to check passengers through baggage scanners (checking the skeletal structure via x-ray).
4. They find and kill 2 aliens.

and the big twist:

> 5. They then realize the two children are also aliens.

any ideas what the name of the movie is ???

Comment: duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/50866/movie-with-children-playing-amongst-travelers-stranded-at-a-bus-station

Comment: thanks for the link, but it seems the question in question was not phrased properly, it was mentioned as "Bus terminal" instead of airport :)

Comment: To clarify: I don't mean to imply that you should have seen the previous question. I'm just linking the two questions for the benefit of moderators and future searchers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is [Terminal Invasion](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0322008/).

> Aliens in human disguise commandeer a rural airport during a
>   snowstorm. To survive, the people trapped inside must determine which
>   of their own is not of this Earth.

[This review](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rKjkGThoC-c) contains some still images from the film that should jog your memory.

Comment: For the record, this film looks **awful**. Might I suggest that instead of rewatching it, you spend that 90 minutes having a bubble bath, pairing up your socks or learning to count to ten in japanese?

Comment: indeed it does.. but I remember the day I was watching it, it was raining heavily outside and not a single good show was getting aired.. so, I saw it :D :D :D

Comment: I'd consider giving it 90 minutes of my time for having Bruce Campbell as lead

Comment: Awful movies are often the best to watch.  Fun-bad, is the term I use to describe them.

Comment: @DaveJohnson - I've read several reviews. Apparently this is just bad-bad.

Comment: I saw it when it came out. I can't say it's the worst B-movie I've seen. I used to really enjoy watching bad Sci-fi shows. If you're into movies that are hilariously bad, this one has Campbell as a plus.

Comment: You should just watch the twilight zone episode with the Martian and Vesuvian in a dinner.

Comment: seeing it now.. it is rightfully fun-bad, specially the x-ray machine part :D :D :D