# In what movie did the alien get its head cut off by a plane propeller?

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I remember seeing this horror movie when I was a child.  There was an alien creature killing the cast in the area.  It disguised itself as other people. At the end of the movie, they had it trapped, and it was in the form of a black man. The man started talking like a girl to show that he was the alien.  The alien died when the planes propeller started and cut off its head.  Does anyone have any idea what movie I am talking about? This has been bothering me for so long. The year of the movie had to be early 2000s

Comment: This sounds like [Terminal Invasion](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0322008/). Could you compare and confirm any other details?

Comment: We don't know when you were a child. Approx year of movie? American? Theatrical/TV?

Comment: Hell yeah dude...it was terminal invasion. This has been bothering me for so long lol thank you

Comment: The current duplicate target was closed as a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81341/film-where-aliens-looking-like-humans-are-waiting-in-an-airport-closed-due-to-sn